# Хранение ресурсов в SPRING MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, я уже просил тут совета по поводу своего примитивного RESTсервиса и надеюсь, что мне помогут и теперь.

Мне необходимо реализовать справочник такси с тремя сущностями (город, страна, служба). Данные справочник должен брать из файлов.

Я практически со всем разобрался и уже знаю как десериализовать json в объекты, как их отдать и прочее, но я не знаю как и где хранить мои json-файлы с данными, нужно илих как-то где-то прописать и прочее. Так же я не понимаю, где находится точка входа у Spring приложений, где мне грубо говоря, писать код, который как раз таки и будет десериализовать эти файлы и забивать их в list-ы, с которыми я смогу работать и отдавать по запросам .

Прошу совета по архитектуре спринга, т.к. чтение доков не сильно помогло.

Answer (score 2):

> как и где хранить мои json-файлы с данными

Вариант "просто в папке" не подойдет?

> Так же я не понимаю, где находится точка входа у Spring приложений

Если это веб-приложение, то явной точки входа у вас не будет (грубо говоря, точкой входа будет веб-сервер Jetty/Tomcat/и т.п., на котором вы разворачиваете приложение).

Если вы пишите обычное standalone приложение, то точка входа будет там, где и всегда - в методе `public static void main(String[] args)`.

> где мне грубо говоря, писать код, который как раз таки и будет десериализовать эти файлы и забивать их в list-ы

Такие вещи как чтение/запись данных как правило делаются в слое DAO (Data Access Objects). DAO - это посредник между вашей бизнес-логикой/контроллерами и фактическим местом хранения данных. Общая суть, в том, что вы пишите классы вида:

```
@Repository          // если вы используете аннотации для поиска зависимостей
class CountryDao {

    public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
        // Тут код, который прочитает файл и замапит его в коллекцию экземпляров Country, например при помощи Jackson или gson.
        // Разумеется, можно закешировать считанную коллекцию в статический хэшмэп, например . 
    }

    public Country getCountryByName(String name) {
        // ....
    }

    public Country findCountriesByPrefix(String prefix) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

И инжектите этот dao в контроллер, где будете им пользоваться:

```
@Controller
class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private CountryDao countryDao;
}
```

Comment: PS. RESTful сервисы в общем случае удобнее делать не средствами Spring MVC, а при помощи одной из реализаций JAX-RS: CXF, Jersey, Restlet.

Comment: у меня на проекте Spring MVC, сервисы сделаны, типа 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/me", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody
 Object  

и не каких проблем с архитектурой )

Comment: @Gorets, это относительно моего ответа или комментария? )

Comment: комментария, хотя лучше его некуда не относить )

Comment: @Nofate как Spring data c JAX-RS использовать? По-моему от Spring MVC разница небольшая

Comment: @Alex78191 в чем именно вопрос? Заинжектить какой-то `JpaRepository` в JAX-RS бин или в промежуточный сервисный бин и вызывать его методы. Постоянно так делаю )